# replaceFirst() fails when replacing with "$"

Tags: java, regex, string

I don't understand why the "$" is special.

```
String str = "bla aa";
String tag = "$";
str = str.replaceFirst("aa", tag);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
```

If I change the tag = "\\$", then it works fine.  But why does it need to be escaped?  thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913709/why-does-replaceall-fail-with-illegal-group-reference for discussion and solution btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is a special regex symbol (in results it's about capturing groups), and [`replaceFirst`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes regex arguments. The documentation explicitly warns you:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceFirst(java.lang.String). Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

Now a bit more about `$`. In the regex pattern it means "end of line".
In the replacement string, `$g` means "the *g* th group". So for a regex `a([a-z]+)([0-9]+)`, you have two groups - `$1` and `$2`, and you can refer to them when replacing. See the [explanation here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: i expect that for the first argument, but why the second argument, which should be a pure substitution?  Maybe I don't understand the functionality of the second argument.

Comment: @user737088 I added in brackets explanation about the sign. I will extend it a bit now.

Comment: it's allowing you to replace things that were captured in a regex group in the first argument.    you have to go all the way into `Matcher.appendReplacement` to see the full explanation.

Comment: for the sun/oracle bug details about this, see http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;?bug_id=6325596

Comment: I wouldn't call it exactly a bug. It is expected with regex replacements.

Comment: I call it a bug, not in the docs but in the exceptions.  If  `appendReplacement()` encounters an unescaped dollar sign or backslash at the end of the replacement string, it blithely tries to match another character, counting on the SIOOB with its worse-than-useless error message to halt the proceedings (which smells like [using exceptions for control flow](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl) to me).  There's even a comment in the source code saying it should throw an IllegalArgumentException instead.

Comment: The problem with all that is that `String.replaceAll(regexp, replacement)` does not document that it treats the replacement String as a regexp behind the scenes. As a programmer I may be interested in using a regexp for matching, but a literal for replacement -- and if there is no corresponding hint in the API doc, I would expect just this to happen.

Comment: As @JonSkeet pointed out, it **is** in the JavaDoc for Java 6 SE `String`, just not on the very first line. Sorry for my flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Replace first takes regular expression. According to [Pattern javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `$` matches The end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

$ matches the end of the line in a regex. So if you need it as a simple character, you need to escape it. You can find more at [JAVA Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: that's the case in a regular expression, but that param isn't a regular expression, its a "replacement", where only \`\\` and `$` have special meaning.

Comment: Right, it's not a regular expression, thanks for pointing this out for me :) I have seen the doc : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,java.lang.String\)