# Why does replaceAll fail with "illegal group reference"?

Tags: java, regex

I am in need to replace

```
\\\s+\\$\\$ to $$
```

I used

```
String s = "  $$";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+\\$\\$","$$");
```

but it throws exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference

Comment: I experience the exact same issue with `replaceFirst()`.  The answers below will also help.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use `"\\$\\$"` in the second parameter:

```
String s="  $$";
s=s.replaceAll("\\s+\\$\\$","\\$\\$");
//or
//s=s.replaceAll("\\s+\\Q$$\\E","\\$\\$");
```

The `$` is group symbol in regex's replacement parameter

So you need to escape it

Comment: Could you also explain me why java is treating the second parameter as regex instead of normal string?

Comment: It's not treating it as a regular expression.  From the documentation for Matcher.appendReplacement, "The replacement string may contain references to subsequences captured during the previous match: Each occurrence of ${name} or $g will be replaced by the result of evaluating the corresponding group(name) or group(g) respectively... A dollar sign ($) may be included as a literal in the replacement string by preceding it with a backslash (\$)."

Comment: the hint about Matcher.quoteReplacement is mandatory for the accepted answer

Comment: Why is also not working in this case? pattern = pattern.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\$");

Answer (score 123):

From [String#replaceAll javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use
>   Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

So escaping of an arbitrary replacement string can be done using [Matcher#quoteReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-):

```
String s = "  $$";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+\\$\\$", Matcher.quoteReplacement("$$"));
```

Also escaping of the pattern can be done with [Pattern#quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)

```
String s = "  $$";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+" + Pattern.quote("$$"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("$$"));
```

Comment: Sincethe replacement string is unknow in 99.99_9%, this answer have much more sence.

Comment: The problem with all that is that `String.replaceAll(regexp, replacement)` does not document that it treats the replacement String as a regexp behind the scenes. As a programmer I may be interested in using a regexp for matching, but a literal for replacement -- and if there is no corresponding hint in the API doc, I would expect just this to happen.

Comment: As @JonSkeet pointed out, it **is** in the JavaDoc for Java 6 SE `String`, just not on the very first line. Sorry for my flaw.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is not the regular expression, but the replacement:

$ is used to refer to `()` matching groups. So you need to escape it as well with a backslash (and a second backslash to make the java compiler happy):

```
String s="  $$";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+\\$\\$", "\\$\\$");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way. Replace the literar $ by escaped \\$
`str.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$")`

Comment: almost.  The result is \$

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
 String msg = "I have %s in my string";

    msg = msg.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("%s"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("$"));
    System.out.println(msg);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I end up implementing replace all with split.
It solved the exception for me

```
public static String replaceAll(String source, String key, String value){
    String[] split = source.split(Pattern.quote(key));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(split[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
        builder.append(value);
        builder.append(split[i]);
    }
    while (source.endsWith(key)) {
        builder.append(value);
        source = source.substring(0, source.length() - key.length());
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` has special meaning in the replacement string as well as in the regex, so you have to escape it there, too:

```
s=s.replaceAll("\\s+\\$\\$", "\\$\\$");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="$$";
        s=s.replaceAll("\\s+\\$\\$","$$");
```

Answer (score -1):

Why the complexity? Why not just replace, so:

```
String s = "  $$";
s = s.replace("\\s+\\$\\$","$$");
```